# How to use one ARM template for Windows and Linux

Tags: visual-studio, azure, virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

I am trying to use one ARM template to deploy Windows and Linux VMs in Azure. Currently I am able to successfully deploy both except that I cant use extra configurations for each without getting an error in Visual Studio. When I select the Option to build Windows VM, there is an error regarding Linux config and Id have to remove that whole line.

```
"linuxConfiguration": {
                "disablePasswordAuthentication": "true",
                "ssh": {
                  "publicKeys": [
                    {
                      "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
                      "keyData": "REMOVED"
                    }
                  ]
                }
```

In StorageProfile, I am stuck only referencing the ID. Is there a way for me not to put the ID every time?

```
"storageProfile": {
              "imageReference": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/91dc1292-e7af-4ae6-807f-aa5b88bf3b79/resourceGroups/DVOPS_DEV_ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/Rhel7singleDisk"
              },
```

Snippet of CODE is below

```
        {
          "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
          "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "hardwareProfile": {
              "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
            },
            "osProfile": {
              "computerName": "[parameters('customVmName')]",
              "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
              "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
              "linuxConfiguration": {
                "disablePasswordAuthentication": "true",
                "ssh": {
                  "publicKeys": [
                    {
                      "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
                      "keyData": "REMOVED"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
/// HOW TO FIX THE STORAGE PROFILE 
            "storageProfile": {
              "imageReference": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/91dc1292-e7af-4ae6-807f-aa5b88bf3b79/resourceGroups/DVOPS_DEV_ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/Rhel7singleDisk"
              },
              "osDisk": {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('customVmName'),'-os')]",
                "createOption": "FromImage",
                "managedDisk": {
                  "storageAccountType": "[parameters('diskStorageType')]"
                }
              },
              "dataDisks": [
                {
                  "name": "[concat(parameters('customVmName'),'-dataDisk-0')]",
                  "lun": 0,
                  "diskSizeGB": 1023,
                  "createOption": "Empty",
                  "managedDisk": {
                    "storageAccountType": "[parameters('diskStorageType')]"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to contain a block of JSON, this is a partial of how I perform a Windows / Linux selection

```
"variables": {
    "Ubuntu": {
        "publisher": "Canonical",
        "offer": "UbuntuServer",
        "sku": "16.04-LTS",
        "version": "latest"
    },
    "Windows": {
        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
        "offer": "WindowsServer",
        "sku": "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers",
        "version": "latest"
    },
    "imageReference": "[variables('Ubuntu')]"
},

"storageProfile": {
    "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]",

    },
```

Like that, you can create as many chunks of JSON as you need, and swap them in wherever required